# A better method to clone original node element

Tags: javascript, function, innerhtml, appendchild, clonenode

```html
<body>
    <ol>
        <li class="clonesonclick">
          <button id="li"><button id="ol">
       </li>
    </ol>
</body>
```

Button clones the parent element i.e `li` and `appendChild()` to `<ol>` and another one clones `<ol>` and `appendChild()` to `<body>`.

I'm using `innerHTML` method to clone `<ol>` but I want only one `<li>` element to be present in next child of body and it's not working What should be the method to get the result?-->

Comment: Please include the javascript you currently have, and it would help if you can make it a runnable [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Node.cloneNode() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode), just don't forget to modify the `id` property ( you can remove it) so you don't end up with duplicate id's.